# understanding how javascript's hasOwnProperty() method evaluates arguments

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and need to check for a nested property. I was told that I can use .hasOwnProperty() method. How would I differentiate between the property being *myVar variable's value*, or the property name actually being myVar in the object? Do I need to extract the content's of myVar into a string before passing into the `hasOwnProperty()`? So basically, does `hasOwnProperty()` always evaluate the argument to the string?

```
 if(main_hash.query.filtered.query.hasOwnProperty(myVar)){
      // do stuff
 }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're essentially asking the difference between `someFunction(aVariable)` and `someFunction('aVariable')`, which is pretty much the same in any language, not just JavaScript.

Comment: But would it evaluate the value stored in aVariable and look that value up on the property of the object, or would it just look on the object to see if it has a property called aVariable?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is a normal function from a parameter passing point of view, so it will use the value passed to it, ie the value of the variable, or in my second example the hardcoded string.  There's no way for a function to know the name of the variable used as a parameter.

Comment: Ahh so it's pass by value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hasOwnProperty doesn't test values per say. It tests if a property exists on an object.

```
var test = {
    someproperty: ''
};

test.hasOwnProperty('someproperty');
```

This would return true because the property exists on the object. I believe it always expects a string value of the property name.

And equivalently doing this is the same:

```
var somevariable = 'someproperty';
test.hasOwnProperty(somevariable);
```

Comment: But what if I pass in a variable that stores a string value, would this actually look for that property based on the value thats stored in the variable?

Comment: Yes, if you have a variable holding a string value of the property name it would test the value stored in the variable for the existence of the property on the object.

Comment: Updating answer with an example.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter, which type of value the variable contains, it will be implicitly converted to a string.